# Reducing recoil with Barret .50 cal

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

What's the most efficient way to reduce the recoil (post-shot, not from breath recovery) on with the Barret?  Is there an optimum combination of attachments / perks to use that will do this?

Comment: haven't played MW2 myself, but the trick on most games is making the vertical movement much faster than normal so that you can quickly recover from recoil

Comment: I dang near voted to close this thinking it more appropriate for the firearms site (when they launch) ... You might consider editing either the title or the text to specify that you're asking about Modern Warfare 2 for those of us who live under rocks and aren't familiar with the abbreviation. (To me, MW will always be MechWarrior ... )

Comment: @john: I have a feeling that's just going to happen.  I did retag cod to call-of-duty, but everyone that plays it knows it as mw2.  I'll take it to meta, though, and see what people think.  One person already agrees with you!

Comment: Are you talking about the recoil after the shot or shaking of the weapon after running out of breath? Just to make sure.

Comment: @Dmitry: good point.  After the shot.  Edited into the question.

Comment: @squillman: Truthfully, had I noticed the tags, I wouldn't have had the initial round (no pun intended) of confusion. Indeed, it was seeing the tags that stopped me from clicking Close. However, I think the tags tend to not be noticed as quickly as the title/text do ...

Comment: @John: yeah, but then I go back and remember all the yapping on MSO about not putting tag fodder in the titles...

Comment: @squillman: True, true. But I think the MSO stuff was more about titles like this: "[Modern Warfare 2] How do I reduce recoil ... ?" It was the specific inclusion of the tags in the brackets before the question, I think. At least, that's how I'd always read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there isn't any way to reduce recoil with the Barrett. Staying crouched and proned while shooting will certainly decrease the recoil, not just for sniper rifles, but on all guns in general.

If you want low-recoil sniper rifles try the WA2000 and the M21 EBR.

Comment: You lose stopping power (not the perk but actual damage caused by the bullet) with the mentioned rifles though. Otherwise good answer :)

Comment: Actually, all sniper rifles deal with the same amount of damage: 70 (50 when silenced). Check out MW2's wikia for more info: http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Call_of_Duty:_Modern_Warfare_2_Weapons

Answer (score 0):

A good way of reducing recoil on any sniper rifle is to use a technique called "quick scoping".  Create a class with sleight of hand pro and stopping power, you can choose any yellow perk (I would go with commando because you will be running a lot).

When you see your target, aim down sight and fire immediately when the snipe scope view appears.  It will take some practice to get use to this method.

This works really well with the intervention.

Here is a video on how to use the quick scope method.

Comment: or on the flip side, de-scope right after the shot and re-scope as close to the shot as possible.  The other thing to remember is not to hold your breath for too long.